# swift array storing data

Tags: arrays, swift, function

I made a function that returns multiple values

```
let interestingNumbers = [   // String:Array<Int>
    "Prime": [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 23],
    "Fibonacci": [1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 80],
    "Square": [1, 4, 9, 16, 25],
]
func largestNum(objDictionary:[String:Array<Int>]) -> (Int,String) {
var largest = 0
var ki:String? = nil
for (kind, numbers) in interestingNumbers {
    for number in numbers {
        if number > largest {
            largest = number
            ki=kind
        }
    }
    }
    return (largest , ki!)
}

print(largestNum(interestingNumbers)) //calling fuction and print

/*var ar2:[Int,String] = largestNum(interestingNumbers))

print(ar2)*/' this code have an error`
```

How can I store the returned values from the function in the array

Comment: What does the error say?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update:**

If you want both values in a single array with `ar[0]` being the `Int` and `ar[1]` being the `String`, then you'll need to declare `ar2` to be `[Any]` and unpack the tuple when initializing `ar2`:

```
let largest = largestNum(interestingNumbers)
var ar2:[Any] = [largest.0, largest.1]

print(ar2) // [80, "Fibonacci"]
```

If you just assign the return to `ar2` and leave it as a tuple, you can access the values with `ar2.0` and `ar2.1`:

```
var ar2 = largestNum(interestingNumbers)
print(ar2.0)  //  80
print(ar2.1)  //  "Fibonacci"
```

Or if you change your `largestNum` to return a named tuple:

```
func largestNum(objDictionary:[String:Array<Int>]) -> (number: Int, kind: String) {
}

var ar2 = largestNum(interestingNumbers)
print(ar2.number)  //  80
print(ar2.kind)    // "Fibonacci"
```

---

**Original Answer:**

Declare your array `ar2` to hold tuples pairs of `Int` and `String`, and then wrap your return value in `[]` to create an array:

```
var ar2:[(Int,String)] = [largestNum(interestingNumbers)]

print(ar2)  // [(80, "Fibonacci")]
```

---

Because tuples are really meant for temporary values, it is better style to store values in an array using a `struct`:

Change your function to return an `InterestingNumber`:

```
struct InterestingNumber {
    let kind: String
    let number: Int
}

func largestNum(objDictionary:[String:Array<Int>]) -> InterestingNumber {
    // contents omitted for brevity

    return InterestingNumber(kind: ki!, number: largest)
}


let largest = largestNum(interestingNumbers)

// Define your array to hold `InterestingNumber`s:   
var ar2:[InterestingNumber] = [largest]

print(ar2)  // [InterestingNumber(kind: "Fibonacci", number: 80)]
```

---

If you meant for `ar2` to just hold a single value, then simply do:

```
var ar2 = largestNum(interestingNumbers)
```

and Swift will infer the type (which is a tuple in your original code or an `InterestingNumber` when using the `struct`.

Comment: thank but i need to but an int in index 0 and string in index1

Comment: You need `ar[0]` to be an `Int` and `ar[1]` to be a `String`?

Comment: If you leave the result as a tuple, `ar2.0` will be an `Int`, and `ar2.1` will be a String.

Answer (score 0):

your code runs fine in xcode 7.3.1 playground

okay, now i get your question:

```
let z: (Int, String) = largestNum(interestingNumbers)
```

The part after the arrow in your function definition is the type (i think called tupel), you can use it for a variable.

Comment: this make a constant object but i need an array